# Opengl black/blank cubemap texture

Tags: opengl-es, sdl, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to use a single cubemap texture for a skybox and reflections, but I just end up with a black texture for both. I am using a temporary array of pixels for the cubemap to make sure the image wasn't the problem. So just ignore the SDL stuff in this function; I commented some of it out. Also the texture functions and shaders are used for both 2d and cubemap textures so I commented that out as well.

**Texture loading**: `zTexture*` vars are class vars

```
bool loadCubeMap(std::vector<const char*> path)
{
    //Texture loading success
    bool textureLoaded = false;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP); //probably not needed

    for(int j=0; j<path.size(); j++)
    {
        //SDL_Surface* cubFacSurf = IMG_Load(path[j]);  
        if(cubFacSurf != NULL)
        {
            //SDL_LockSurface(cubFacSurf);              
            zTextureW = cubFacSurf->w;
            zTextureH = cubFacSurf->h;
            textureLoaded = loadFromPixels((GLuint*)cubFacSurf->pixels, zTextureW, zTextureH, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_RGB, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+j);
            //SDL_UnlockSurface(cubFacSurf);
            //SDL_FreeSurface(cubFacSurf);
        }
        if(textureLoaded == false)
        {
            SDL_Log("Unable to load %s\n", path[j]);
        }
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return textureLoaded;
}
```

main pixel loader

```
bool loadFromPixels(void* pixels, GLuint width, GLuint height, const GLenum tType = GL_TEXTURE_2D, const GLenum glPix = GL_RGB, const GLenum tFace = GL_TEXTURE_2D)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &zTextureID);
    glBindTexture(tType, zTextureID);

    GLfloat checkerboard[] = {1.f,1.f,1.f,  0.f,0.f,0.f,    0.f,0.f,0.f,    1.f,0.f,1.f};
    if(tType == GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)
        glTexImage2D(tFace, 0, glPix, 2, 2, 0, glPix, GL_FLOAT, &checkerboard);
    //else
    //glTexImage2D(tFace, 0, glPix, width, height, 0, glPix, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    //Check for error
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        SDL_Log( "Error loading texture from %p pixels! %d\n", pixels, error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Texture Binding**:

```
void apply(const GLenum typ = GL_TEXTURE_2D)
{
    glEnable(typ); //Probably not necessary doesnt change anything if left out
    if(typ == GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP); //same here
        glUniform1i(mainTxtrID, 0); //mainTxtrID = Textr in frag
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //and here
        glUniform1i(cubeID, 1); //cubeID = TextCub in frag
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    }
    glBindTexture(typ, zTextureID);
}
```

**"Uber" Shaders:**
vertex:

```
#version 100  
precision mediump float;  

uniform mat4 ModelMat;  
uniform mat4 ViewMat;  
uniform mat4 ProjMat;  
uniform mat4 OrthMat;

uniform bool world;  
attribute vec4 vPosition;  
attribute vec2 UVCoordAt;  
attribute vec3 nPosition;  
varying vec2 UVCoord;  
varying vec3 vPos;  
varying vec3 vNor;  
varying vec3 vRefl;  

void main()  
{  
    UVCoord = UVCoordAt;  
    vPos = vec3(vPosition);  //skybox coords
    vNor = normalize(vec3(ModelMat * vec4(nPosition,0.0)));  
    vRefl = reflect(normalize(vPos - vec3(ViewMat[3][0], ViewMat[3][1], ViewMat[3][2])), vNor); //reflection direction vector 
    if(world)
            gl_Position = ProjMat * ViewMat * ModelMat * vPosition;
    else    gl_Position = OrthMat * ModelMat * vPosition;
}
```

fragment:

```
#version 100  
precision mediump float;  

uniform samplerCube TextCub;  
uniform sampler2D Textr;  
uniform vec3 LiPos;  
uniform vec4 fragCol;  

uniform bool lighting;  
uniform bool dimen;  
uniform bool isRefl;  
varying vec2 UVCoord;  
varying vec3 vPos;  
varying vec3 vNor;  
varying vec3 vRefl;

void main()  
{  
    vec4 textVect = texture2D(Textr, UVCoord);  //default texturing
    if(dimen){    textVect = textureCube(TextCub, vPos);    }  //skybox
    else if(isRefl){    textVect = mix(textVect, textureCube(TextCub, vRefl), 0.7);    }  //reflections mixed with default textr
    if(lighting){ 
        float diffuse = clamp(dot(vNor, LiPos), 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_FragColor = clamp(diffuse*2.0, 0.6, 1.1) * fragCol * textVect;  
    }  
    else{   gl_FragColor =  fragCol * textVect; }
}
```

I am using `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, I doubt this affects anything. I am guessing the problem is in the `apply()` function or something else I left out. There are extensions for cubemaps but I assume the default opengles 2 cubemaps work without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new texture for each cubemap face. In the `loadFromPixels()` function, which you call for each face:

```
glGenTextures(1, &zTextureID);
glBindTexture(tType, zTextureID);
...
glTexImage2D(...);
```

This means that you will end up with 6 textures that each have only data for one face specified, which makes them incomplete.

You need to create **one** cubemap texture, and then specify data for all 6 sides of that cubemap.